Rendering markers in GmapControl WinForms
I need advice, because I don't know what to do anymore.
I have a GPS where I use UDP to send a log at a speed of 100x per second.
I'm using the Nuget Gmap.NET.WindowsForms wrapper to display the current location, which works fine.
The problem arises when I insert tags that they insert from a database where I contain certain information and a given location.
This means that I have set a tolerance and if the current GPS value given in the database approaches, then a marker is drawn on the map, the last one is deleted and the next one is drawn. I limited it to displaying a maximum of 10 brands. (The database contains approximately 150,000 brands.)
If I have this method active, rendering becomes very slow and the process no longer works in real time but with a delay.
I hope I explained it clearly.
Don't know where the problem might be?
Thanks for your advice
 private void SearchTP()
 {
     double zemSir = Math.Floor(g_Latitude * 100000) / 100000;
     double zemPol = Math.Floor(g_Longitude * 100000) / 100000;
     const int MaxMarkersToInsert = 10; //LIMITED to 10 brands
     int insertedMarkerCount = 0; //LIMITED to 10 brands

     for (int i = 0; i < linecount; i++) //asynchronous call to BeginInvoke methods. This allows the map control to be updated from another thread, which is often necessary if updates are happening from the GUI thread.
     {
         if ((zemPol >= st[i].zem_delka - 0.00001 && zemPol <= st[i].zem_delka + 0.00001) &&
             (zemSir >= st[i].zem_sirka - 0.00001 && zemSir <= st[i].zem_sirka + 0.00001))
         {
             textBoxTP.Invoke(new Action(() => textBoxTP.Text = st[i].cislo.TrimStart('0')));
             textBoxUsek.Invoke(new Action(() => textBoxUsek.Text = st[i].usek.Substring(1)));
             textBoxKolej.Invoke(new Action(() => textBoxKolej.Text = st[i].kolej.ToString()));

             gMapControl1.Invoke(new Action(() => markers.Markers.Clear()));
             for (int y = 0; y < linecount && insertedMarkerCount < MaxMarkersToInsert; y++) 
             {
                 if ((zemPol >= st[y].zem_delka - 0.001 && zemPol <= st[y].zem_delka + 0.001) &&
                     (zemSir >= st[y].zem_sirka - 0.001 && zemSir <= st[y].zem_sirka + 0.001))
                 {
                     VlozZnackyDoMapy(st[y].cislo, st[y].zem_sirka, st[y].zem_delka);
                     insertedMarkerCount++; 
                 }
             }
             gMapControl1.Invoke(new Action(() => gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(markers)));
             //gMapControl1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => gMapControl1.Refresh()));
             break;
         }
         
     }           
 }

 private void VlozZnackyDoMapy(string tpDoMapy, double poziceX, double poziceY)
 {
     tpDoMapy = tpDoMapy.TrimStart('0');

     gMapControl1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
     {
         GMapMarker marker = new GMarkerGoogle(
             new PointLatLng(poziceX, poziceY),
             GMarkerGoogleType.blue_pushpin);

         marker.ToolTip = new GMapBaloonToolTip(marker);
         marker.ToolTip.Fill = Brushes.Transparent; // Transparent background
         marker.ToolTip.Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold); // Label text color
         marker.ToolTip.Stroke = Pens.Transparent; // Transparent border
         marker.ToolTip.Offset = new Point(-5, -35); // Move the label up above the marker
         marker.ToolTipMode = MarkerTooltipMode.Always;

         //Here we alternate the colors of the text according to the index of the created mark
         if (markers.Markers.Count % 2 == 0)
             marker.ToolTip.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
         else
             marker.ToolTip.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;

         marker.ToolTipText = tpDoMapy;
         markers.Markers.Add(marker);
     }));
 }

Create an asynchronous method, inserting all markers into the map.
